# Clarification about break function and continue function

Tags: c, while-loop, break, continue

Below is my `while` loop. What will happen if `fgets == NULL` and what will happen if I use `continue` and `fgets == NULL` ? Explanation expected.

```
while((len = recv(sock, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply), 0)) > 0) 
{
        printf("point1\n");
        printf("Server reply: %.*s", len, server_reply);
        printf("point2\n");

        printf("Enter message : ");
        printf("point3\n");
        if (fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        printf("point4\n");

        //send some data
        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

          printf("point5\n");

}
```

Comment: `break` and `continue` are not functions, they are *statements*. That is, they are special keywords that are recognized directly by the compiler.

Comment: No, the function will *not* exit the `if` loop. `break` is for `for`, `while`, and `switch` only. Does that help?

Comment: Check by yourself with a _simpler_ program...`continue` will restart with `printf("point1\n");`

Comment: `if` is not a loop. And `break` and `continue` are not functions. Don't invent these definitions yourself.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti no, it will restart with `len = recv...`

Comment: @mch yes, I thought `while` condition evaluation is pretty implicit in `while` definition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` statement breaks out of the closest loop. And no, `if` is a conditional statement and not a loop statement. Loop statements are `for`, `while` and `do ... while`.

The `continue` statement continues the closest loop at the next iteration.

---

Example using `break`:

```
printf("before loop\n");

int i = 0;
while (1)  /* an infinite loop */
{
    if (i == 2)
        break;

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    ++i;  /* increase `i` by one */
}

printf("after loop\n");
```

If you put the above in a program, it will print

```
before loop
i = 0
i = 1
after loop
```

---

Example using `continue`

```
printf("before loop\n");

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
{
    if ((i % 2) == 0)  /* Check if `i` is even */
        continue;

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
}

printf("after loop\n");
```

The above code will print

```
before loop
i = 1
i = 3
i = 5
after loop
```

---

When I say "closest loop" above I mean that if you have nested loops, that is a loop within a loop, only the loop where the `break` or `continue` statement is in will be affected.

For example

```
for (...) /* Some `for` loop */
{
    while (...)
    {
        ...

        for (...)
        {
            ...

            continue; /* will continue the innermost `for` loop only */

            ...
        }

        ...

        break;  /* Will break out of the `while` loop only */

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Everything clear. Thanks a lot!